# Trying to understand this weird Java / hibernate-jpamodelgen behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpamodelgen

I'm trying to understand a weird behaviour related to `hibernate-jpamodelgen` but maybe more to Java in general.

I have entities and I generate code via `hibernate-jpamodelgen`. That all works but then I tried something that cost me a few days and a lot of headaches.

Here is the version that works.

```java
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME})
    List<Course> findAll();

}
```

I thought I would make the code a bit more beautiful and put the String `Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME` into a variable.

```java
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {

    // this is new
    static final String TOPIC_NAME = Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME;
    
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME})
    List<Course> findAll();

}
```

That still works but as soon as I use this variable `TOPIC_NAME` I cannot compile anymore.

```java
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {

    static final String TOPIC_NAME = Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME;
    
    // this DOES NOT work
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {TOPIC_NAME})
    List<Course> findAll();

}
```

When I try to compile via `gradle compileJava` I'm suddenly getting errors like

```
  symbol:   variable Student_
  location: interface StudentRepository
/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Course/CourseRepository.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    static final String TOPIC_NAME = Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME;
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable Course_
  location: interface CourseRepository
/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Course/CourseRepository.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    static final String TOPIC_NAME = Course_.TOPIC + "." + Student_.NAME;
```

Why is that the case? I'm happy that I found the issue but I don't understand why this happens.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In relation to the compile error, when you use it, you had the generated sources for Course_ class (probably you've done that in an IDE and no errors occurred). When performing gradle compileJAva, those sources probably got clean away, hence the errors. That same type of errors occur in maven with generated sources. You have to use plugins that solve this problem (generate before compile).

Comment: I've found this old page for that plugin https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/jpamodelgen/reference/en-US/html_single/. Here, in maven case, you can indicate the phsa (generate-sources). Probably you need something similar.

Comment: I don't think this is really the issue. I always cleaned the generated sources before trying something else. As soon as I used the `static final String` in the `attributePaths` the problem appeared. I could easily reproduce this issues.